# Identification of location and type of bi-plane

Tags: united-states, military, aircraft, identification

[image]

Could the location be on the west coast or in Hawaii? 1920s time frame?

Comment: Counting the stars on the flag often works for a US time frame.

Comment: It's a 48-star grid, so sometime between 1912 and 1959.  Doesn't narrow things down much.

Comment: The models of cars could help date it.  My non-expert opinion would be late '20s.  Location resembles southern California.

Comment: looking at old pictures of pearl harbor bases they almost all have palm trees in the pictures so id say stateside is a good bed.

Comment: @mgkrebbs - Not that this means much, but there are other places that resemble that location. I know the AFB/Airport in Albuquerque happens to abut the (Sandia) mountains very much like that.

Comment: I would bet its a bay area airfield. Problem is that there were a lot of them.

Comment: There's not much to go on from the aircraft. Biplane, single engine, fixed gear with no fairings over the wheels. The lower wing appears to be directly below the upper, but it's hard to tell. The rudder is horizontally striped and there's a single vertical stripe on the rear of the body which might indicate what unit they're part of. Might have more luck identifying the model of cars.

Comment: It's not Wheeler Army Airfield, or any on Oahu. That range doesn't match at all, either the Leeward or Windward ranges.

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to see any detail of the aircraft but they do look like they could be DH4's which were in US service from 1918-1932, which while a very wide time window is consistent with the vehicles in the picture.

[image]
*Formation of DH4s, 1920s, US National Archives*